# ¿Por qué un apuntador es capaz de imprimir un string?

Tags: c, punteros

Quiero saber el porqué, usando apuntadores, esta sección de código imprime de manera correcta el string "Amarillo"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    char *color;
    color = "Amarillo";
    
    printf("El color es: %s\n", color);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Así es como trabajan los punteros, y `"%s"` es el *flag* usado para imprimir cadenas. El código hace lo que tiene que hacer, no hay nada raro en él.

Comment: A lo que me refería es que quiero saber ¿Por qué funciona? Principalmente porque no había visto antes que los punteros se usarán así, siempre he visto que al crear un puntero éste se asigna a la dirección de un dato.

Comment: Hola Brandon. Eso que mencionas es justo lo que pasa en el ejemplo. Color es un puntero y apunta directo a la dirección de memoria donde el programa esta almacenando la cadena Amarillo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un puntero es una variable que almacena la dirección de un espacio en memoria. Cuando haces:

```
char *color;
```

Estas creando una variable que apunta a un espacio en memoria, por defecto al no ser inicializada tendrá como contenido la dirección 0 (ver comentario de [MrDave1999](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375333/por-qu%C3%A9-un-apuntador-es-capaz-de-imprimir-un-string/375346?noredirect=1#comment673604_375346)), podemos ver esto si imprimimos el valor del puntero (la dirección en memoria a donde apunta):

```
printf("Contenido del puntero \"color\": %x \n\n",color);
//===========Resultado:===========
//Contenido del puntero "color": 0
```

Ahora, cuando escribes:

```
color = "Amarillo";
```

Estás haciendo dos cosas:

1. Definiendo una string que consiste en un array de caracteres que finalizan en el carácter de final de línea `\0` para saber dónde finaliza. Esta variable es constante y no tiene nombre (variable anónima). Esto lo puedes comprobar utilizando el operador `&` para acceder la dirección de esta variable:

   ```
   printf("Dirección de la variable constante \"%s\": %x \n\n","Amarillo",&("Amarillo"));
   //===========Resultado:===========
   //Dirección de la variable constante "Amarillo": 0x400714
   ```

   Puedes imprimir la dirección en cualquier lugar de tu código y verás como siempre va a imprimir la misma, porque tu compilador creó una variable constante para "Amarillo" y cuándo utilizas esa string en tu código, estás haciendo referencia a ella.
2. Asignas el valor del puntero a la dirección de la nueva variable:

   ```
     printf("Contenido del puntero \"color\": %x \n\n",color);
    //===========Resultado:===========
    //Contenido del puntero "color": 0x400714
   ```

Ahora de aquí nacen preguntas:

*¿Si el puntero apunta a un array de variables, apunta a cada carácter al mismo tiempo?*

R/ Cuando creas un array siempre se guarda o se apunta a la dirección del primer elemento, los arrays son variables que ocupan espacios **contiguos** en memoria, puedes comprobarlo con este código:

```
void imprimirElementos(char * stringerino){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stringerino); i++)
    {
        printf("%s[%d] : %c, dirección:%x\n",stringerino,i,stringerino[i],&stringerino[i]);
    }
}

imprimirElementos(color)
//===========Resultado:===========
//Amarillo[0] : A, dirección:400714
//Amarillo[1] : m, dirección:400715
//Amarillo[2] : a, dirección:400716
//Amarillo[3] : r, dirección:400717
//Amarillo[4] : i, dirección:400718
//Amarillo[5] : l, dirección:400719
//Amarillo[6] : l, dirección:40071a
//Amarillo[7] : o, dirección:40071b
```

Mira como la dirección del primer elemento de la string coincide con el valor del puntero `color`, en otras palabras, el puntero `color` apunta al primer elemento de nuestro array de caracteres (string). Así es como almacenamos y manejamos los strings, al hacer `color[N]` estamos diciendo que queremos acceder al elemento en la dirección a la que apunta el puntero `color` con un desplazamiento de `N` posiciones en memoria. Esto se puede demostrar con el siguiente código en donde accedemos el valor de r de "Amarillo", es decir, el caso `N=3`:

```
printf("*(color+3) = %c\n",*(color+3));
printf("color[3] = %c\n",color[3]);
//===========Resultado:===========
*(color+3) = r                                                                                                         
 color[3] = r
```

*¿Cómo es que la función `strlen()` o `printf("El color es: %s\n", color);` saben cuánto mide mi string si solo estoy apuntando al primer elemento?*

R/ En C las strings están terminadas por el carácter `\0` que indica que la string finalizó. Las funciones anteriores buscan este carácter en el array para saber el tamaño de la misma, esto quiere decir que el tamaño de "Amarillo" no es realmente 8, si no 9, contando este carácter. Una muestra:

```
char color1[] = {'r','o','j','o','\0'};
char color2[] = {'a','z','u','l','\0'};
printf("color1=%s\n",color1);
printf("color2=%s\n",color2);
//Sabemos que color1 es:
//color1[0] : r
//color1[1] : o
//color1[2] : j
//color1[3] : o
//color1[4] : \0
//Si reemplazamos color1[4] por una letra X entonces el programa no sabrá donde termina la string
//y seguirá buscando por un '/0', casualmente el que sigue es el de la string color2
color1[4] = 'X';
printf("color1=%s\n",color1);
printf("color2=%s\n",color2);
//===========Resultado:===========
//color1=rojo
//color2=azul
//color1=rojoXazul
//color2=azul
```

Espero que esto sea de ayuda.

Comment: Si modificas lo de `como no le asignas ningún valor se inicializa apuntado a cero` y lo de `Creando una variable de tipo "string"`, tienes mi +1

Comment: Gracias por las correcciones

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy eficiente, por fin podré dormir tranquilo :D

Comment: Si el puntero es definido en un ámbito local el valor por defecto no será `0`, tendrá simplemente *basura*. Si fuera un puntero con ámbito global, ahí si el compilador inicializa el puntero a `NULL`.